# XGBoost best tree path

Tags: classification, boosting

I observed something that I could not make sense. Best tree inside the model uses same feature twice in a row. But the the thing I did not get is that: The first condition implies second condition. I attaching the screenshot. Just observe the "yes,missing" path of "f40" you will see what I mean.

Thanks a lot[image: Best tree in XGBoost model]

Answer (score 0):

The path uses two different numeric thresholds (even if "Yes greater than threshold" and "missing" both go in the same direction each time). I.e. it is important enough to distinguish different levels of feature f40 to split it repeatedly within the tree, which can then in a crude step-function way approximate complex non-linear functional relationships.

Comment: I thought "yes" implies condition is met rather than "Yes greater than threshold", which in this example it would be  "Yes smaller than threshold". Which would imply there will be no points in the node that follows "no" at the second f40 split. Am I getting something wrong here? Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I did not look carefully enough. If that is really what the visualization means, then that really makes no sense. I would double check the visualization really means that. Unless something was really, I cannot see how xgboost could possibly do such a split.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also dumped the tree structures to a txt file to check if there is a problem with visualization. But the split is same, in fact it seems like there are data points in the path that follows "no". I am thinking this may be due to using histogram based trees (the ones that build histogram at each node). But it does not make sense to me even with hist. based trees or there is something particular that I do not know about hist. based trees